# How to fix incorrectly UTF-8 decoded string?

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm consuming data from a RESTful API, it returns me strings and integer values. However, it seems it's returning some string values incorrectly encoded/decoded (probably).

Expected string:

```
criança
```

String received:

```
crianÃ§a
```

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://analytics.us.algolia.com/2/searches?index={index}&startDate={yesterday}".format(index=index, yesterday=yesterday)
headers = { 'X-Algolia-Application-Id': app_id,
            'X-Algolia-API-Key': app_key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response_json = json.loads(response.text)

print(response_json)
```

This is for a Python 3.6.x script that will get data from Algolia's RESTful API and store it in Amazon Redshift. I'm writing this script on Ubuntu 18.04, my Terminal character encoding set is `pt_BR.UTF-8` (`echo $LANG`) and UTF-8 (`locale charmap`).

I see the received data is wrong when I print it before storing it in database - which is set to use `charset=utf8`. I can also see this wrong data in database, through `SELECT` statement.

I found this [UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), it points out that probably it happened because of UTF-8 bytes being interpreted as Windows-1252 (or ISO 8859-1) bytes.

How can I treat it using some Python function/lib?

Comment: This means that the response was treated as ASCII instead of UTF8. It's not a matter of encoding. The page you read right now is UTF8 and yet, if you check the source you'll see there's no encoding involved. Please post your code. Most likely there's a call there that tries to "decode" or convert that string into something else, thus *causing* the problem

Comment: Another possibility is that the string is correct but the way you *check* it isn't. If your terminal or console isn't set to UTF8, the UTF8 bytes will be displayed as if they were ASCII characters and the two bytes that represent `ç` will appear as `Ã§`. If you saved the data to a file, you may be reading it as ASCII instead of UTF8

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your support.
I've checked my Terminal character encoding, it's set to UTF-8. Is there any setting I should explicitly do to make Python work with UTF-8?

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't need anything. Post your code. Somehow *it* treats the response as ASCII instead of UTF8. Or it could be that the response has the wrong `charset` in the `Content-Type` header. What happens when you try to retrieve *this* page?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos technically it isn't printing ASCII, because those characters are outside ASCIIs range. In Python 3.6 all strings should be automatically decoded into Unicode on input and converted to the appropriate encoding on output. I agree that we really need to see  some code to see what's going on.

Comment: I just edited the post, there's the code, guys.

Comment: What is the response header Content-Type? What are the bytes for criança in the response body?

Comment: @MarkRansom pick your own name for `single byte codepage`. No matter which you pick, ASCII or ANSI, someone always says it's the other way round. I ended up using `US-ASCII` for the 7-bit codepage, ASCII for everything else, and this comment when needed

Comment: @GabrielAtaide `Content-Type` is only allowed in PUT/POST requests. In GET it can only appear as a *response* header. Use `Accept-Charset` to request a UTF8 response. I suspect the HTTP service you call defaults to Latin1 (aka 1252, ISO-8859-1)

Comment: @GabrielAtaide even so, the response *is* UTF8 and the terminal *should* display it correctly. Most likely the problem is a misconfigured environment. Try setting `LC_ALL` to `pt_BR.UTF-8` or even `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requests` library tries to [guess the encoding of the response](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).
It's possible `requests` is decoding the response as `cp1252` (aka Windows-1252).

I'mg guessing this because if you take that text and encode it back to `cp1252` and then decode it as `utf-8`, you'll see the correct text:

```
>>> 'crianÃ§a'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
'criança'
```

Based on that, I'd guess that if you ask your response object what encoding it guessed, it'll tell you `cp1252`:

```
>>> response.encoding
'cp1252'
```

Forcing `requests` to decode as `utf-8` instead, like this, will probably fix your issue:

```
>>> response.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have a default encoding, unless you mean UTF16. Strings in Windows are UTF16. The *user's* and *system's* locale affects how *non-*Unicode text is treated. In any case, the OP mentioned that Ubuntu is used, and the `$LANG` environment variable (`pt_BR.UTF-8`) shouldn't cause a problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wrote that in an unclear way. I didn't mean to imply the operating system encoding mattered. The requests library uses some heuristics to guess the encodings (I just added a link to the docs about that). It may have guessed the Windows-1252 encoding, likely based on an an incorrect HTTP header.

Comment: @TreyHunner, thank you! It worked! Still, when I received a correct string like `criança` an exception was raised: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 5: invalid continuation byte`. Thus, I had to add a `try`to use your solution and, for a correct string received scenario, an `except` containing: `text = text.encode('cp1252').decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`. This way I can treat the response as utf-8 in any case.

Comment: @GabrielAtaide, it sounds like you sometimes receive bytes that are actually utf-8 encoded properly. In that case, that encoding as cp1252 and then decoding as utf-8 would result in an error like the one you linked. You may want to read `response.content` and use the [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) library to guess the encoding for you and then manually decode the bytes. That way you could avoid re-encoding incorrectly guessed bytes and hoping for the best.

Answer (score -2):

if the problem persists, copy your project to a different folder, import your project anew with a different project file name . Restart your Android Studio first , then import the project from a different folder and you should have cleared the problem !